# Query `RETURN true, false;` doesn't work inside Memgraph, what's the alternative query that produces equivalent results?

Tags: memgraphdb

Query `RETURN true, false;` doesn't work inside Memgraph, what's the alternative query that produces equivalent results? I get the error `Multiple results with the same name 'true' are not allowed`.

```
Memgraph Lab is running at localhost:3000

mgconsole 1.3
Connected to 'memgraph://127.0.0.1:7687'
Type :help for shell usage
Quit the shell by typing Ctrl-D(eof) or :quit
memgraph> RETURN true, false;
Client received exception: Multiple results with the same name 'true' are not allowed.
memgraph>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality doesn't work for any literal values, the solution is to make distinct aliases, e.g. `RETURN true AS x, false AS y;`.